# Using a reflected attribute in a column_property in sqlAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I have a question that may have a straightforward answer, regarding SQLAlchemy ORM (using 2.0).

I have an existing model in a PostgreSQL database, holding:

- message headers in a table named `single_recipient_message_header` (holding a primary key column named `id`). This table is reflected in a `HeaderORM` class (see code below).
- messages in a table named `single_recipient_message`, (holding a foreign key column towards `single_recipient_message_header.id` named `header_id`). This table is reflected in a `MessageORM` class.

I would like to build a `column_property` that will count the number of messages related to the message header, using a SQL expression (stolen from [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property)).

However, I can't find a way to reference the `HeaderORM.id` attribute in this column property, apart from accessing the `__table__` attribute.

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    DeclarativeBase,
    Mapped,
    relationship,
    column_property,
)

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class MessageOrm(Base):
    __table__ = Table(
        "single_recipient_message",
        Base.metadata,
        autoload_with=engine,   # engine is set up at this point in another part of the code
    )

    header: Mapped["HeaderOrm"] = relationship(
        back_populates="single_recipient_messages"
    )


class HeaderOrm(Base):
    __table__ = Table(
        "single_recipient_message_header",
        Base.metadata,
        autoload_with=engine,
    )

    single_recipient_messages: Mapped[List["MessageOrm"]] = (
        relationship(back_populates="header")
    )
    msg_count = column_property(
        select(func.count(MessageOrm.id))
        .where(MessageOrm.header_id == id)  # This throws as 'id' is not defined in enclosing class
        .correlate_except(MessageOrm)
        .scalar_subquery()
    )
```

The only way I managed to make this work is by replacing the where clause that is throwing (see code above) to:

```py
        .where(MessageOrm.header_id == __table__.c.id)
```

but I feel like mixing SQLA Core with ORM concepts is a bad idea (I am quite new to SQLAlchemy).

What would be the most 'alchemist' way to make this `column_property` work?

Answer (score 0):

I will leave this question open as I think that getting insight from the community might be helpful for other people regarding this topic. However, I would like to share the way I managed to get away with this.

Please note that the `__table__.c.` workaround did work, without any side effect I could notice.

The other solution I found is related to the fact that I had to use the [Deferred Reflection feature](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#using-deferredreflection) of SQLAlchemy ORM in my application context (engine is not ready at the time of class declaration).

The idea is that classes are declared with just a few attributes in the first place, and are enriched after the engine is available. This gives access to the class name during the `column_property` declaration.

See the code below:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    DeclarativeBase,
    Mapped,
    relationship,
    column_property,
)

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Reflected(DeferredReflection):
    # required to define ORM class prior to engine creation
    # need to call Reflected.prepare() when engine is ready
    __abstract__ = True


class MessageOrm(Reflected, Base):
    __tablename__ = "single_recipient_message"

    header: Mapped["HeaderOrm"] = relationship(
        back_populates="single_recipient_messages"
    )


class HeaderOrm(Reflected, Base):
    __tablename__ = "single_recipient_message_header"

    single_recipient_messages: Mapped[List["MessageOrm"]] = (
        relationship(back_populates="header")
    )

engine = create_engine()  #  function which initializes the engine

Reflected.prepare(engine=engine)  #  reflects the "deferred reflection" tables

HeaderOrm.msg_count = column_property(
    select(func.count(MessageOrm.id))
    .where(MessageOrm.header_id == HeaderOrm.id)  #  HeaderOrm name is now accessible.
    .correlate_except(MessageOrm)
    .scalar_subquery()
)
```